# Export normal map from unity?

Tags: unity, normal-mapping, export

In unity I can create a normal map out of a black and white image (By changing the type to normal map and select create from grayscale) Im wondering if there is a way to export the normal map like it should look so I don't need to create it from grayscale when I use it in another project?

Answer (score 1):

There is a script available to get this job done. You can follow the instructions specified in the link given below :)

### [ExportNormalmap](http://wiki.unity3d.com/index.php?title=ExportNormalmap)

Or else you can check this online tool to get normal maps from images

http://cpetry.github.io/NormalMap-Online/

Comment: That exports it more like a height map than a normal map is just grey and white

Comment: Is there any other program than unity that converts grayscale to normal maps that you know of?

Comment: Check this tool. You can convert images to normal maps http://cpetry.github.io/NormalMap-Online/